# Testeo de método

Tags: java

> Estoy tratando de realizar un testeo de este método pero no encuentro la manera correcta de realizarla espero puedan ayudarme. El siguiente código es el método a testear.

```
 public Contrato esVerificarContratoVIgente(Contrato contrato) {
        Contrato contratovigente = null;
        Date fechaactual = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
        if (fechaactual.compareTo(contrato.getFecha_fin()) < 0 || fechaactual.compareTo(contrato.getFecha_fin()) == 0) {
            if (contrato.getEstado().equalsIgnoreCase("activo")) {
                contratovigente = contrato;
            }
        }
        return contratovigente;
```

> Este es código del testeo que estoy realizando

```
    @Test
public void testEsVerificarContratoVIgente() {
    System.out.println("esVerificarContratoVIgente");
    Date fechaactual = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
    Contrato contratovigente = null;
    Contrato contrato = new Contrato();
    contrato.setFecha_inicio(fechaactual);
    contrato.setFecha_fin("30/12/2021");
    Contrato expResult = null;
    Contrato result = contrato.esVerificarContratoVIgente(contrato);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese método devuelve el parámetro que le pasas si se cumplen ciertas condiciones y en otro caso devuelve null. Creo que hay dos fallos aquí:

- Ese método no necesita parámetros, ya que pertenece al propio objeto que quieres comprobar.
- Debería devolver un boolean:

  ```
  Contrato c = ...
  if (c.esContratovigente()) {
      ...
  }
  ```

Podrías escribir el código así:

```
public boolean esVerificarContratoVigente() {
    Date now = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
    return (now.compareTo(this.getFecha_fin()) < 0 ||
             now.compareTo(this.getFecha_fin()) == 0) && 
         this.getEstado().equalsIgnoreCase("activo");
}
```

Y el test:

```
@Test
public void testEsVerificarContratoVIgente() {
    System.out.println("esVerificarContratoVIgente");
    Date fechaactual = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
    Contrato contrato = new Contrato();
    contrato.setFecha_inicio(fechaactual);
    contrato.setFecha_fin("30/12/2021");
    assertEquals(true, contrato.esVerificarContratoVIgente());
}
```

Comment: Vaya vaya, don Lozano. Así a ojo diría que ese código no compila! `public Contrato esVerificarContratoVigente() {` debería ser `public boolean esVerificarContratoVigente() {`, no? :P

Comment: Bien visto! Corregido